# What happens when the kernel_task is killed?

Tags: macos, kernel

What happens when you kill kernel_task on OS X? Is that even possible? I know that the system reboots because of kernel panic when you kill launchd, but I can't find any resources online and am afraid of trying to kill kernel_task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't properly kill kernel_task. Activity Monitor doesn't allow you to kill kernel_task at all - neither as admin nor as root.

If you try to outwit kernel_task by using `kill -9 0` or `/bin/kill -9 0` as root you just kill yourself i.e. the first command kills bash (kill is an integrated command of bash) and the second command kills `/bin/kill` because in both cases the 0 is interpreted as me/yourself and **not** as kernel_task.

The man page for the system call `kill` (which is called by both `kill` and `/bin/kill`) explains that

```
If pid is zero:
    Sig is sent to all processes whose group ID is equal to the process group ID of
    the sender, and for which the process has permission; this is a variant of
    killpg(2).
```

This makes it basically impossible to even attempt to kill the process with PID 0.

Comment: Well said - it's the kernel that does the executions, so it's far easier to just shut down the OS instead of changing it (hot patch or not) to self-kill and then work out any engineering issues where processes that depend on the kernel now crash due to the change that has happened. This is also why kernel panics bring the system to an abrupt halt.

Answer (score -6):

You cannot kill kernel_task because it represents the MacOS kernel. The kernel is the core of the MacOS operating system, and the kernel starts all other processes on the computer-even launchd. Killing kernel_task would be the same as trying to remove something from itself-in this case, trying to remove the operating system from the operating system.
The only way kernel_task would be killed is if it experiences an internal error. But then, it's not being killed... it's crashing